# dropdown does not work

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have the page http://www.supersprox.eu/invoicewithtabs/. When I click "Show filter" button an area with several dropdowns appear. The problem is I can not select values of the first row of dropdowns. When I click, for example, first "Field name" dropdown a list with values do not appear, although HTML-code of the page shows that there are values in that dropdown with `id='fiedname00'`(values are Invoice, Stamping, Part number, Quantity etc.). But I can not change the initial value that was set when page loaded. But when I press "Add condition" button that add new portion of dropdowns, these new dropdowns allow to change their values. Why this happens? On local computer, without WordPress everything works fine, but on WordPress site there is an issue described. I am using WordPress 3.9.2.

```
    <select id="fieldname00" onchange="populatedropdown('0')">
    <option>Invoice</option>
    <option>Stamping</option>
    <option>Part number</option>
    <option>Quantity</option>
    <option>Order number</option>
    <option>Anodal</option>
    <option>LILS</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: It's a JavaScript specific Question, and is off-topic here. It has no relation with WordPress. Better ask in [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a item over these select boxes. In you css file search for element.style and remove it's position: relative; property.

```
element.style {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
}
```

That will fix this issue.

Comment: how did you find out that problem is with style? @Roberthue

Comment: Very simple answer, Firebug. ;)